# Link to library for Scala parser combinators in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala, parser-combinators

I created an Eclipse project using parser combinators using Scala 2.10.  Recently I upgraded the Scala IDE plugin in Eclipse to version 3.0.4, which includes Scala 2.11.  This new version of Scala has removed the `scala.util.parsing.combinator` package from the core Scala library.  As a consequence, my upgraded Eclipse project has a plethora of "not found" errors.

The Scala website has some instructions for adding Maven and SBT dependencies for parser combinators.  However, I can't find any instructions on scala-lang.org or scala-ide.org for linking to parser combinators.  The full download of Scala (http://www.scala-lang.org/download/) includes a JAR for parser combinators, but I can't find the source attachment JAR for debugging. The Scala Eclipse plugin lacks the parser library (even though it includes other spun-out libraries like Scala Swing).  I don't want to use Maven or SBT.

What is the easiest way to add Scala parser combinators (including source attachment) to an Eclipse project?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way *is* to use Sbt or Maven. Otherwise you need to manually download the jar file and corresponding sources from [here](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.scala-lang.modules%7Cscala-parser-combinators_2.11%7C1.0.2%7Cbundle).

You can add the scala-parser-combinators.jar to your build path (Project Properties -> Java Build Path), and then go to `Libraries`, click on `Add External Jar`. Once you have the jar, navigate to `Source Attachment` under the jar name and double-click to attach sources.

Answer (score 0):

Please take my example projects as a starting point. They are using `sbt` so you can import them into Eclipse.

The 1st is a relatively simple expression parser https://github.com/scala-szeged/top-calc-dsl

The 2nd is a complete example language interpreter in 200 lines handling nested if, while, int, bool, array and variables https://github.com/scala-szeged/hrank-while-language